List running and queued jobs in AzureML workspace
The documentation to list jobs using the AzureML REST API is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/jobs/list?view=rest-azureml-2024-04-01&tabs=HTTP
However this query can return hundreds of completed jobs. I'm interested to filter the list server-side to only queued or running jobs. I have not been able to specify the right combination of properties directives to get these jobs- what is the secret sauce?
Notably AzureML Studio uses a different API at https://ml.azure.com/api/.../entities to fetch this list but this API isn't supported by the Az REST CLI.
